Preventing white space above chapter heading
When I want a chapter heading as follows

what I get is something as this

As we see, there is small space above chapter heading. Previous answers as in this question only reduce space above chapter heading
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{twoside=false}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\NewDocumentCommand{\upperRuleTikZ}{O{1} O{gray}   O{0pt}}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, opacity=#1, color=#2]
        \draw[line width=#3]
        (current page text area.north west)
        --
        (current page text area.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{bophook}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\AtBeginPage{%
    \upperRuleTikZ
}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\headrulewidth}{}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% titles customizations
% BEGIN_FOLD

% \chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}
% shape
[block]
% format
{\bfseries\huge}
% label
{\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter}
% sep
{0em}
% before code
{\space-\space}

% \chapter
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
% left
{0em}
% before sep
{-\baselineskip}
% after sep
{\baselineskip}
% right sep
[0em]

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\noindent%
{\bfseries\huge\chaptertitlename\space1\space-\space Title}

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}


If you position it so the letters touch the top of the text area, the chapter heading will be higher than text of the same size on other pages which are not chapter headings. Most likely that text won't be as large, but the top of the chapter heading will still be higher than the top of that text because there will always be a gap between the top of the text area and the top of the text making up the first line. That will look really quite odd imho. If anything, the chapter heading should be lower; it certainly shouldn't be higher than text on subsequent pages.

what would you do if it was \^{C}hapter it probably isn't but tex doesn't know that, the baseline spacing is almost always larger than the capital height
